# Woocommerce Product Add-ons modification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So here is the link of the addon:

http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/

I want to find the template to make some changes and mainly to change places of the two fields: so the field with checkboxes is going second and the description field is third. 
There is a link with all the addon files(a bit modified but it is generally the same). : 
https://github.com/nextime/woocommerce-better-product-addons

So I would be so happy if you help me to find the place where I need to modify

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to edit the template files within this plugin. That is  not a good idea because they will be deleted when you update the extension.

The add-on plugin makes use of the `woocommerce_get_template();` function when calling these templates. This means that you can create a directory in your active theme folder titled "woocommerce". You may already have this directory for other template overrides. Then create a directory in that named "addons", and copy any template that you want to override into this directory. SO to override the addon-start.php template your theme file should be located:

`path/to/your/theme/woocommerce-product-addons/addons/addon-start.php`

Templates within WooCommerce extensions that make use of the `woocommerce_get_template();`will follow the same template

Comment: I edited the path because it wasn't the right one. You must use the plugin's folder name, not `woocommerce` in your theme.

Answer (score 2):

The correct location to add templates you wish to override is

```
path/to/your/theme/woocommerce-product-addons/addons/[template-name].php
```

Because it is an extension, the override files must be in a theme subfolder of the same name as the plugin, and all of the templates for this particular plugin are in a subfolder named "addons."  It took me a bit of tweaking @Leon Francis Shelhamer's answer to get it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found! For those who has the same question: 
/templates/addons/addon-start.php

Comment: Yes, that is the location of the template. But you should never edit these files in the plugin's folder. Next time there is an update, you'll lose your changes.

Answer (score 0):

for your plugin

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'theme_addon_height_width_wc_get_template', 11, 5 );

function theme_addon_height_width_wc_get_template( $located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path )
{
    if ( $template_name && $template_path == 'woocommerce-product-addons' ) {

        $temp_overrade_arr = array( 'addons/addon-start.php', 'addons/select.php', 'addons/addon-end.php' );

        if ( in_array( $template_name, $temp_overrade_arr ) ) {
            $plugin_template_path = untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ).'/woocommerce-product-addons/'.$template_name;
              // exit;
            if ( file_exists( $plugin_template_path ) ) {
                $located = $plugin_template_path;
            }
        }

    }
    return $located;
}
```